# Why was this flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I flagged an answer on [What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements/52908#52908) as not an answer. It now states that the flag was disputed. This answer has 8 upvotes and is posted by a semi-high rep user, but it does not provide an answer to the question.

Am I wrong here? I also think the other 6 answers are duplicates of the accepted answer. I don't know if that matters, though.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP is asking why the flag is disputed, not what a disputed flag is.

Comment: I think that would be perfectly fine to close-as-duplicate, given the only answer you can give to 'why was this flag disputed' is 'because some other people voted to dispute it'.  If the question is "Should this answer be deleted", well, that's a different question title isn't it?

Comment: @Joe That's the point. I flagged it because by my understanding of SO policy, it is not an answer and should be deleted. So this question is asking why others think it should not be deleted. ChrisF's answer even states that he wouldn't have flagged it, although no reason as to why he wouldn't have flagged it was stated.

Comment: Mate, I had more clearer situation 2 days ago. User removed question content and put "Downvoters are morons" (or something similar), I've flagged that and it was disputed. So, obviously we're all different and we all have different criteria.

Comment: Looks like the answer was deleted.

Comment: Converted to a comment by @false, specifically.

Comment: Someone's in for a shock when they try to work out why they lost all that rep.

Answer (score 11):

It was disputed because another user didn't agree with your flag.

You are not necessarily wrong, but I don't think I would have flagged it.

Re your aside about the answers being duplicates: All the answers (apart from one) were provided within 5 minutes the question being asked so were probably posted independently of each other. The only time you should be flagging answers as "duplicate" is if they were added much later than the rest and don't add any new information.

Comment: I didn't flag any as duplicate. I flagged the answer with 8 upvotes because it is not an answer.

Comment: @Tom - "I also think the other 6 answers are duplicates of the accepted answer." I was addressing this part of your question.

Comment: To be more precise, three users in review thought it did not need to be deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5132094 , triggering the dispute on the flag.

Comment: Any reason as to why? These are the reasons I don't bother maintaining the site. I take the time to say "hey, this doesn't make sense", and I get the note that it was disputed with absolutely no details. I have to post a meta question to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong. Makes me wonder why I bothered in the first place.

Comment: @Tom: Because three people didn't agree with your assessment doesn't mean you did anything wrong. It just means that they didn't agree.

Comment: I think it was pretty clearly a good flag. The flagged answer makes **no** attempt to actually answer the question (of why square brackets are needed), just makes a flippant remark that would not even be useful as a comment.

Comment: I would have flagged as well, this was a terrible non-answer. I'm surprised it got *any* "Looks good" reviews in the queue.